# Total revenue between two dates not working c# ms access database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I am creating a C# project with an MS Access as the database back-end. I want to show the sum of prices between two dates. I have create the following query method:

```
public DataTable selectDates(string dateFrom,string dateTo)
{
    initilize();
    _conn.ConnectionString = _cs;
    _cmd.Connection = _conn;

    _cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(tPrice) AS Price from [tblInventory] where Date_Of_Installation BETWEEN '" + dateFrom + "' AND '" + dateTo + "'";
    _da.SelectCommand = _cmd;
    _da.Fill(_dt);
    return _dt;
}
```

On the form end I have two time pickers and a button:

```
private void btnTotalRevenue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = db.selectDates((pickerDateFrom.Text).ToString().Trim(), (pickerDateTo).ToString().Trim());
    string a = dt.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(a);   
}
```

but the messagebox is showing an empty string: [image].

Comment: As has been noted in the answers, date literals in Access queries need to be wrapped with `#` characters, and should be in `M-D-Y` instead of `D-M-Y`. However, consider using [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of messing around with string formatting (aside from the general benefits of avoiding SQL injection, and enabling reuse of query plans).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MS Access you need to format your dates and wrap them in # symbols.

example.

```
SELECT Sum(tPrice) AS Price from [tblInventory] 
WHERE Date_Of_Installation BETWEEN #2016/01/01# AND #2016/02/01#
```

So your C# should become.

```
private void btnTotalRevenue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = db.selectDates(pickerDateFrom.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#"), pickerDateTo.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#"));
    string a = dt.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(a);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query to :

```
 _cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(tPrice) AS Price from [tblInventory] where
 Date_Of_Installation BETWEEN '" + dateFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  + "' AND '" + 
 dateTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  + "'";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use DateTime parameters in methode selectDates like this :

```
public DataTable selectDates(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
{
    initilize();
    _conn.ConnectionString = _cs;
    _cmd.Connection = _conn;
    string query = string.Format("Select Sum(tPrice) AS Price from [tblInventory] where Date_Of_Installation BETWEEN #{0}# AND #{1}#", dateFrom.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), dateTo.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    _cmd.CommandText = query;
    _da.SelectCommand = _cmd;
    _da.Fill(_dt);
    return _dt;
}
```

and call method wiyhout casing value of DateTimePicker to string like this :

```
void btnTotalRevenue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = db.selectDates(pickerDateFrom.Value, pickerDateTo.Value);
    string a = dt.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(a);
}
```

But, I advice you to use the Parameter to use DbType.DateTime and then pass the DateTime directly to the parameter (do not need to convert) , and also avoid SQL injections , like this :

```
public DataTable selectDates(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
{
    initilize();
    _conn.ConnectionString = _cs;
    string query = "Select Sum(tPrice) AS Price from [tblInventory] where Date_Of_Installation BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";
    OleDbCommand _cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, _conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate ", DbType.DateTime).Value = dateFrom;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate ", DbType.DateTime).Value = dateTo;
    _da.SelectCommand = _cmd;
    _da.Fill(_dt);
    return _dt;
}
```

Comment: This might be an easier way to define the query method, but as an answer to this question it only repeats what has been said before -- Access date literals need to be wrapped with `#`.

Comment: What's new in your answer ?

Comment: @ZevSpitz : first I have to open the question before, I have not seen the answers, 2nd my answer is different to the previous ones, because what I recommended to use the DateTime parameters in the method because it casts of the answers présedante does not work with a string type

Comment: @BeldiAnouar you can see my response to ZevSpitz, and if I can say that, what's new in your answer relative to the first.

Comment: @BeldiAnouar the syntax in `dateFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` in query is worong because `dateFrom` is string in method.